# delete entity foreign key relationship springs

Tags: java, spring-data

I have two tables in a relationship with each other.
When I delete a line of data in the parent table.
If the data stream that is used in the table, the error message.
If not, to delete data[image]

SQL Server Foreign Key Update and Delete Rules

No Action : Not allowed. Error message would be generated. (I want to use this exception)

Delete row in Ma_DM_NGAN_HANG throw Exception

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "Ma_DM_NGAN_HANG", schema = "dbo", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "MANH"))
public class DmNganHang implements java.io.Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// Fields

private Long id;
private String manh;
private String tennh;
private String tentat;
private String diachi;
private String dienthoai;
private String fax;
private String email;
private String taikhoan;
private String masothue;
private Integer idDonvi;
private String website;
private String filter;
private List<DmNhanVien> dmNhanViens = new ArrayList<DmNhanVien>();
private List<DmDoiTacTknganhang> dmDoiTacTknganhangs = new ArrayList<DmDoiTacTknganhang>();

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public DmNganHang() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public DmNganHang(Long id, String manh, String tennh, String taikhoan) {
    this.id = id;
    this.manh = manh;
    this.tennh = tennh;
    this.taikhoan = taikhoan;
}

/** full constructor */
public DmNganHang(Long id, String manh, String tennh, String tentat,
        String diachi, String dienthoai, String fax, String email,
        String taikhoan, String masothue, Integer idDonvi, String website,
        String filter, List<DmNhanVien> dmNhanViens,
        List<DmDoiTacTknganhang> dmDoiTacTknganhangs) {
    this.id = id;
    this.manh = manh;
    this.tennh = tennh;
    this.tentat = tentat;
    this.diachi = diachi;
    this.dienthoai = dienthoai;
    this.fax = fax;
    this.email = email;
    this.taikhoan = taikhoan;
    this.masothue = masothue;
    this.idDonvi = idDonvi;
    this.website = website;
    this.filter = filter;
    this.dmNhanViens = dmNhanViens;
    this.dmDoiTacTknganhangs = dmDoiTacTknganhangs;
}

// Property accessors
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 18, scale = 0)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// Code ......

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dmNganHang")
public List<DmNhanVien> getDmNhanViens() {
    return this.dmNhanViens;
}

public void setDmNhanViens(List<DmNhanVien> dmNhanViens) {
    this.dmNhanViens = dmNhanViens;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dmNganHang")
public List<DmDoiTacTknganhang> getDmDoiTacTknganhangs() {
    return this.dmDoiTacTknganhangs;
}

public void setDmDoiTacTknganhangs(
        List<DmDoiTacTknganhang> dmDoiTacTknganhangs) {
    this.dmDoiTacTknganhangs = dmDoiTacTknganhangs;
}
```

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Ma_DM_NHAN_VIEN", schema = "dbo", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "MANV", "IdDonvi" }))
public class DmNhanVien implements java.io.Serializable {

```
// Fields

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private DmNganHang dmNganHang;
private DmPhongBan dmPhongBan;
private String manv;
private String tennv;
private String diachi;
private String hkthuongtru;
private String dienthoai;
private String masothue;
private String socmt;
private Date ngaycap;
private String noicap;
private Boolean canhancutru;
private String nhom;
private String taikhoannh;
private String tinhtranghonnhan;
private Boolean gioitinh;
private Date ngaysinh;
private Integer idDonvi;
private String filter;
private List<TnChungtuthunhap> tnChungtuthunhaps = new ArrayList<TnChungtuthunhap>();
private List<TnNguoiphuthuoc> tnNguoiphuthuocs = new ArrayList<TnNguoiphuthuoc>();
private List<DmHopDong> dmHopDongs = new ArrayList<DmHopDong>();

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public DmNhanVien() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public DmNhanVien(Long id, DmNganHang dmNganHang, DmPhongBan dmPhongBan,
        String manv, String tennv, String diachi, String taikhoannh) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dmNganHang = dmNganHang;
    this.dmPhongBan = dmPhongBan;
    this.manv = manv;
    this.tennv = tennv;
    this.diachi = diachi;
    this.taikhoannh = taikhoannh;
}

/** full constructor */
public DmNhanVien(Long id, DmNganHang dmNganHang, DmPhongBan dmPhongBan,
        String manv, String tennv, String diachi, String hkthuongtru,
        String dienthoai, String masothue, String socmt, Date ngaycap,
        String noicap, Boolean canhancutru, String nhom, String taikhoannh,
        String tinhtranghonnhan, Boolean gioitinh, Date ngaysinh,
        Integer idDonvi, String filter,
        List<TnChungtuthunhap> tnChungtuthunhaps,
        List<TnNguoiphuthuoc> tnNguoiphuthuocs, List<DmHopDong> dmHopDongs) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dmNganHang = dmNganHang;
    this.dmPhongBan = dmPhongBan;
    this.manv = manv;
    this.tennv = tennv;
    this.diachi = diachi;
    this.hkthuongtru = hkthuongtru;
    this.dienthoai = dienthoai;
    this.masothue = masothue;
    this.socmt = socmt;
    this.ngaycap = ngaycap;
    this.noicap = noicap;
    this.canhancutru = canhancutru;
    this.nhom = nhom;
    this.taikhoannh = taikhoannh;
    this.tinhtranghonnhan = tinhtranghonnhan;
    this.gioitinh = gioitinh;
    this.ngaysinh = ngaysinh;
    this.idDonvi = idDonvi;
    this.filter = filter;
    this.tnChungtuthunhaps = tnChungtuthunhaps;
    this.tnNguoiphuthuocs = tnNguoiphuthuocs;
    this.dmHopDongs = dmHopDongs;
}

// Property accessors
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 18, scale = 0)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_NGANHANG", nullable = false)
public DmNganHang getDmNganHang() {
    return this.dmNganHang;
}

public void setDmNganHang(DmNganHang dmNganHang) {
    this.dmNganHang = dmNganHang;
}

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PHONGBAN", nullable = false)
public DmPhongBan getDmPhongBan() {
    return this.dmPhongBan;
}

// Code .....
```

}

Method Delete

```
public <T, E extends Serializable> void delete(T entity) {
    entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}
public <T, E extends Serializable> void deletefindOne(T entity) {
    E id = (E) CommonUtil.invoke(entity, "getId");
    JpaRepository repository = new SimpleJpaRepository(entity.getClass(),
            entityManager);
    repository.delete(repository.findOne(id));
}
```

Thanks